# How do I make an parent resize when child element image is resize in percentage?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I have a block level element which has a "image" as a child element. When i downsize image in percentage, block level element do not fit according to the new size of image, however block level parent element holds the 100% position of child image.

I want parent element to respect the size as i change the child element size in percentage. Here is the link showing the problem:

http://codepen.io/rosn/pen/ZOoGgm

codepen html:

```
<a href="#">
  <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/236x/f6/35/e7/f635e7cdfcf59c09236a44df28f53d92.jpg" alt="" />
</a>
```

codepen css:

```
a{
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid red; 
}

img{
    width: 70%;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

**Problem trying to solve in Bootstrap:** 
To be more precise, this problem was caused in bootstrap navigation, when i applied a bigger image inside "navbar-brand". when i decreased the screen size "navbar-brand" was flowing below "nav-collapse" button as shown in the figure.

[image]

In order to make the logo small and fit in the same line as the "nav-collapse" button, i tried to downsize the image using media query using width in percentage however the parent shown in red border does not sink with the downsize image.

Here is the link of bootstrap code of real problem: 
http://codepen.io/rosn/pen/JKvGvr?editors=1100

and this screen shot shows the logo image dropping in small size using the percentage width. Please decrease the screen width and you will have a replicate of the problem. 
[image]

Comment: 1) Your codepen uses `width: 10vw;` instead of `width: 70%;`. Which value do you need? 2) Please add your bootstrap code into your answer.

Comment: @GlebKemarsky i have changed vw to %.  You can see the problem with % now in my code pen. 

Using vw fixed the problem but i am not sure of using vw. And actual problem caused by using percentage is still there.

Comment: `70%` just means `70% of the width of the parent block`. In your [codepen](http://codepen.io/rosn/pen/ZOoGgm) the `<a>` block is a parent block for the image. So it's not a problem, it's the behavior that you have demanded.

Answer (score 0):

#### 1) Image

1. `vw` is a percentage of the window width; `%` is a percentage of the width of the parent block. [In your codepen](http://codepen.io/rosn/pen/ZOoGgm) the `<a>` block is a parent block for the image. So `70%` just means `70% of the width of the <a>`. Thus, the empty space to the right of the image is not a problem. This is the behavior that you have demanded.
2. You can use media queries to control the width of the image on the screens of different sizes. For example:

   ```
   img { width: 30vw; } }
   @media (min-width: 481px) { img { width: 20vw; } }
   @media (min-width: 768px) { img { width: 10vw; } }
   ```
3. By default an image has the `display` property with the value `inline`. Because of this the border of the parent block departs from the lower edge of the image. So you need to redefine this property as `block`.
4. In the demo I prefer to use [the `outline` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/outline) instead of the `border` property:

   > Outlines do not take up space, they are drawn above the content.

http://codepen.io/glebkema/pen/wWjrWN

```css
a {
  display: inline-block;
  outline: 1px solid red; 
}

img {
  display: block;
  outline: 1px solid blue;
  width: 30vw;
}
@media (min-width: 481px) { img { width: 20vw; } }
@media (min-width: 768px) { img { width: 10vw; } }
```

```html
<a href="#">
  <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/236x/f6/35/e7/f635e7cdfcf59c09236a44df28f53d92.jpg" alt="" />
</a>
```

#### 2) Bootstrap

1. You can set the image size in pixels, and the parent block will adjust to this:

   http://codepen.io/glebkema/pen/grzPyN

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css');

.navbar-brand {
  outline: 1px solid red;
  padding: 0 15px;
}
  
.navbar-brand img {
  outline: 1px solid blue;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="jumbotron">
  <div class="container">

    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
      <div class="container-fluid">

        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"> 
            <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/236x/f6/35/e7/f635e7cdfcf59c09236a44df28f53d92.jpg" alt="" />
          </a>
        </div>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#">our services</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">tour package</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">custom tour</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">travel partners</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">contactus</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        
      </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="row text-center">
      <h1>Intro text</h1>    
      <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">Book a trip</a>
    </div>

  </div><!--container end -->
</div><!--jumbotron end -->

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

2. Or you can set the width of the parent block in pexels. And apply the `width: 100%;` property to the image.

   http://codepen.io/glebkema/pen/PzZNPo

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css');

.navbar-brand {
  outline: 1px solid red;
  padding: 0 15px;
  width: 80px;
}
  
.navbar-brand img {
  outline: 1px solid blue;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="jumbotron">
  <div class="container">

    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
      <div class="container-fluid">

        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"> 
            <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/236x/f6/35/e7/f635e7cdfcf59c09236a44df28f53d92.jpg" alt="" />
          </a>
        </div>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#">our services</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">tour package</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">custom tour</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">travel partners</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">contactus</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        
      </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="row text-center">
      <h1>Intro text</h1>    
      <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">Book a trip</a>
    </div>

  </div><!--container end -->
</div><!--jumbotron end -->

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: i used the same technique to fix it temporarily. But i found using vw causes image logo to be very small trying in one of the small media break point. 

i appreciate your solution, but please recommend if there are better way to do it. Also original problem of using percentage is itself weird and wonder how people do it using percentage.

Comment: On the small media you can use different width of the image by media-query. For example: `@media (max-width: 480px) { img { width: 30vw; } }`.

Comment: @rosnk I've updated my answer. But still I'm not sure I understand what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you may need to consider,

## 1. Bootstrap has fixed height (50px) for `navbar-brand`.

So, It does not allow any child element to flow above 50px. We need to reset it as

```
.navbar-brand{
 height:auto;
}
```

Also, you also need to set the `padding:0` for that to make your image bigger.

## 2. Directly applying width for `<img>` is not a good idea.

In your case you have give `width:30%`.  which makes it to flow it in next line in mobile resolution. So, you can ignore the width and try giving height for the image.

Try this,

```
.navbar-brand{
  border: 1px solid red;
  height:auto;
  padding:0;
}
  
  .navbar-brand img{
    width: auto;
    max-height:48px;
    vertical-align:center;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

Have a look at this forked and updated version of your codepen.
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WxJRmL?editors=1100

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure a CSS-only option is available.  Your display: inline-block is creating a box that encompasses 100% of the required space even though you've told the child image to only render in 70% of it.

You could take display: inline-block away, and then wrap your anchor element with a mini table (as tables have an inherent 'shrink to fit' mentality) but tables often get a bad rep and it's a bit heavy handed just to force this result.

Edit: by 100% of the required space, I mean the space required by the children elements hosted inside the inline-block.  So even if you shrunk a child to 70% or 50%, the inline-block has already 'reserved' space for the element at the 100% dimensions.

Comment: `display: inline-block` does not create a box that takes up 100% of available space, you're thinking of `display: block;`. `inline-block` allows you to do thinks like set `width` and `height` on and `inline` element.

Comment: I don't disagree with you, I think I just wasn't clear on my meaning (sorry).  I mean that the box is created to cover 100% of the space required by the original size of its own children.

Comment: Sorry again for not clarifying that to begin with.  Since it was the context of the problem to begin with, I glossed over it.  Pretty-please reverse the down-vote if you can understand and accept my clarifications?  Thanks.

Comment: Here it is with the solution in place to demonstrate: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XKqmxJ

Comment: I'm sorry, but a table is **not** a proper solution.